# Metric spaces containing a topological disc

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, embeddings

It is well-known that every connected, locally connected compact metrizable space $X$ contains an arc, that is, a subspace homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Are there topological properties we can add to these hypotheses to ensure that $X$ contains a subspace homeomorphic to $[0,1]^2$?

My naive guess is to demand that $X$ has covering dimension $\dim(X)\geq 2$ but I wouldn't be surprised if this is still insufficient.

Comment: Yes, this is insufficient, Pontryagin surface would be an example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I gather a Pontryagin surface is a certain connected sum of infinitely many projective planes, and relevant properties are that it is 2-dimensional, homogeneous and not locally contractible (hence cannot contain a 2-disk). What is a good reference for the properties?

Comment: Iff there exists a quotient map from $R^{2}$ onto a subspace of $X$ such that each point preimage is a non separating continuum, and so that the point preimages form an upper-semi-continuous decomposition of the plane. There is some redundancy in this answer if $X$ has a reasonable topology.

Comment: If $X$ is metric then $X$ contains a disk iff there exists a map from $R^{2}$ onto a subspace $Y$ of $X$, such that compacta in $Y$ have compact preimage, and so that the preimage of each $y$ in $Y$ does not separate the plane.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I think "A useful functor and three famous examples in topology" by Williams or "Degree-one, monotone self-maps of the Pontryagin surface are near-homeomorphisms" by Daverman and Thickstun.